# Send multiple data between pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am making an application in visual studio for windows phone C#
I have two text boxes on main page.
I want to send their content to second page.
but i am not able to do it

I am able to send only one text box (name1) but not other (name2)using

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?msg=" + name1.Text, UriKind.Relative));
```

please help

Comment: What makes it impossible to send name2? Where do you encounter the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on if the values in your textboxes are to create some form of internal state or not, I would create a static class that holds the current state.

When text is entered into the box, update 2 strings on this static class. The class will obviously still be available to pull data from in your future pages, and also if the user happens to hit 'Back' in the application. It will probably help you when you extend it in the future to hold more data also.

However, there should be no issue in passing across multiple values using the `Uri` method that you're using at the moment, you could simply do this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?msg=" + name1.Text + "&name2=" + name2.Text, UriKind.Relative));
```

Note that `Uri` navigation isn't the best way to pass your parameters, though.

Answer (score 0):

You must override `OnNavigatedFrom` method in your code. Take a look [here](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2011/03/passing-values-to-windows-phone-7-pages-destination-page-instance-within-onnavigatedfrom-method/).

Sorry, wrong method. I would write something like that:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{ 
Page2 page2 = e.Content as Page2;
page2.textBox.text += name1.text;
page2.textBox.text += name2.text'
}
```

Comment: What exactly, where is the problem?

Comment: i got in mainpage.xaml two text boxes name1 and name2

and i have to send its data to two textblock abc and def respectively in page1.xaml

Comment: Exactly. You must find a moment, when you are navigating to another page. Therefore you need to create a special method. There you can define how your 'abc' text field must be initialized. OnNavigateTo method gets reference to your Page1 as a parameter.

Comment: Try to read this page http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Navigation-in-depth--Navigation-Framework .

Answer (score 0):

The question has been asked before here :-

[Windows Phone Navigation - Passing back to the page before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316511/windows-phone-navigation-passing-back-to-the-page-before)

The thread provides three different approaches for making data accessible between pages and removes the requirement for setting data in query strings.

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?msg=" + name1.Text, UriKind.Relative));


Cant we modify this only?