# how to navigate to specific pivotitem on back button click in uwp app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am creating a Windows 10 app, in which I have 2 xaml pages. The first xaml page (say, A) have 3 pivot items. The second page (say, B) have back button functionality. I want the page B to navigate back to the second pivot item of page A. How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pivot` has `SelectedIndex` property. You need to setup index which you would like.

To pass parameters back you can choose variant, which you want:

1. [Global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10316704/5114112)
2. [Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10316571/5114112)
3. You can use Messenger from GalaSoft